# Hibernate get value of foreign key not object reference

Tags: hibernate

I am learning hibernate and I am trying to retrieve the value of a foreign key to display in a datatable. My entity classes are below

Tbl Event

```
package Society;
// Generated 25-Oct-2017 07:05:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


> import java.util.Date; import java.util.HashSet; import java.util.Set;
> import javax.persistence.Entity; import
> javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import

> javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Tblevent generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
public class Tblevent  implements java.io.Serializable {

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer eventId;
     private String eventName;
     private String eventAddress1;
     private String eventAddress2;
     private String eventAddress3;
 private String eventTown;
 private String eventPostcode;
 private String eventCountry;
 private Date eventStartDate;
 private Date eventEndDate;
 private String eventDesc;
 private Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses = new HashSet<Tbleventattendees>(0);

public Tblevent() {
}


public Tblevent(String eventName, String eventAddress1, String eventAddress2, String eventTown, String eventPostcode, String eventCountry, Date eventStartDate, Date eventEndDate, String eventDesc) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.eventAddress1 = eventAddress1;
    this.eventAddress2 = eventAddress2;
    this.eventTown = eventTown;
    this.eventPostcode = eventPostcode;
    this.eventCountry = eventCountry;
    this.eventStartDate = eventStartDate;
    this.eventEndDate = eventEndDate;
    this.eventDesc = eventDesc;
}
public Tblevent(String eventName, String eventAddress1, String eventAddress2, String eventAddress3, String eventTown, String eventPostcode, String eventCountry, Date eventStartDate, Date eventEndDate, String eventDesc, Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses) {
   this.eventName = eventName;
   this.eventAddress1 = eventAddress1;
   this.eventAddress2 = eventAddress2;
   this.eventAddress3 = eventAddress3;
   this.eventTown = eventTown;
   this.eventPostcode = eventPostcode;
   this.eventCountry = eventCountry;
   this.eventStartDate = eventStartDate;
   this.eventEndDate = eventEndDate;
   this.eventDesc = eventDesc;
   this.tbleventattendeeses = tbleventattendeeses;
}

public Integer getEventId() {
    return this.eventId;
}

public void setEventId(Integer eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
}
public String getEventName() {
    return this.eventName;
}

public void setEventName(String eventName) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
}
public String getEventAddress1() {
    return this.eventAddress1;
}

public void setEventAddress1(String eventAddress1) {
    this.eventAddress1 = eventAddress1;
}
public String getEventAddress2() {
    return this.eventAddress2;
}

public void setEventAddress2(String eventAddress2) {
    this.eventAddress2 = eventAddress2;
}
public String getEventAddress3() {
    return this.eventAddress3;
}

public void setEventAddress3(String eventAddress3) {
    this.eventAddress3 = eventAddress3;
}
public String getEventTown() {
    return this.eventTown;
}

public void setEventTown(String eventTown) {
    this.eventTown = eventTown;
}
public String getEventPostcode() {
    return this.eventPostcode;
}

public void setEventPostcode(String eventPostcode) {
    this.eventPostcode = eventPostcode;
}
public String getEventCountry() {
    return this.eventCountry;
}

public void setEventCountry(String eventCountry) {
    this.eventCountry = eventCountry;
}
public Date getEventStartDate() {
    return this.eventStartDate;
}

public void setEventStartDate(Date eventStartDate) {
    this.eventStartDate = eventStartDate;
}
public Date getEventEndDate() {
    return this.eventEndDate;
}

public void setEventEndDate(Date eventEndDate) {
    this.eventEndDate = eventEndDate;
}
public String getEventDesc() {
    return this.eventDesc;
}

public void setEventDesc(String eventDesc) {
    this.eventDesc = eventDesc;
}
public Set<Tbleventattendees> getTbleventattendeeses() {
    return this.tbleventattendeeses;
}

public void setTbleventattendeeses(Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses) {
    this.tbleventattendeeses = tbleventattendeeses;
}
```

}

Tblmembers

```
    package Society;
// Generated 25-Oct-2017 07:05:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Tblmembers generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
public class Tblmembers  implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer memberId;
     private String memberFirstName;
     private String memberFamilyName;
     private String memberPassword;
     private String memberMiddleNames;
     private String memberUserName;
     private Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses = new HashSet<Tbleventattendees>(0);

    public Tblmembers() {
    }


    public Tblmembers(String memberFirstName, String memberFamilyName, String memberPassword, String memberUserName) {
        this.memberFirstName = memberFirstName;
        this.memberFamilyName = memberFamilyName;
        this.memberPassword = memberPassword;
        this.memberUserName = memberUserName;
    }
public Tblmembers(String memberFirstName, String memberFamilyName, String memberPassword, String memberMiddleNames, String memberUserName, Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses) {
   this.memberFirstName = memberFirstName;
   this.memberFamilyName = memberFamilyName;
   this.memberPassword = memberPassword;
   this.memberMiddleNames = memberMiddleNames;
   this.memberUserName = memberUserName;
   this.tbleventattendeeses = tbleventattendeeses;
}

public Integer getMemberId() {
    return this.memberId;
}

public void setMemberId(Integer memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}
public String getMemberFirstName() {
    return this.memberFirstName;
}

public void setMemberFirstName(String memberFirstName) {
    this.memberFirstName = memberFirstName;
}
public String getMemberFamilyName() {
    return this.memberFamilyName;
}

public void setMemberFamilyName(String memberFamilyName) {
    this.memberFamilyName = memberFamilyName;
}
public String getMemberPassword() {
    return this.memberPassword;
}

public void setMemberPassword(String memberPassword) {
    this.memberPassword = memberPassword;
}
public String getMemberMiddleNames() {
    return this.memberMiddleNames;
}

public void setMemberMiddleNames(String memberMiddleNames) {
    this.memberMiddleNames = memberMiddleNames;
}
public String getMemberUserName() {
    return this.memberUserName;
}

public void setMemberUserName(String memberUserName) {
    this.memberUserName = memberUserName;
}
public Set<Tbleventattendees> getTbleventattendeeses() {
    return this.tbleventattendeeses;
}

public void setTbleventattendeeses(Set<Tbleventattendees> tbleventattendeeses) {
    this.tbleventattendeeses = tbleventattendeeses;


 }
```

}

tblEventAttendees

```
    package Society;
// Generated 25-Oct-2017 07:05:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;




/**
 * Tbleventattendees generated by hbm2java
 * 
 */

@Entity
public class Tbleventattendees  implements java.io.Serializable {

     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer eventAttendeeRecord;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "eventId")
     private Tblevent tblevent;
@OneToMany
 private Tblmembers tblmembers;
 private String memberComments;

public Tbleventattendees() {
}

public Tbleventattendees(Tblevent tblevent, Tblmembers tblmembers, String memberComments) {
   this.tblevent = tblevent;
   this.tblmembers = tblmembers;
   this.memberComments = memberComments;
}

public Integer getEventAttendeeRecord() {
    return this.eventAttendeeRecord;
}

public void setEventAttendeeRecord(Integer eventAttendeeRecord) {
    this.eventAttendeeRecord = eventAttendeeRecord;
}
public Tblevent getTblevent() {
    return this.tblevent;
}

public void setTblevent(Tblevent tblevent) {
    this.tblevent = tblevent;
}
public Tblmembers getTblmembers() {
    return this.tblmembers;
}

public void setTblmembers(Tblmembers tblmembers) {
    this.tblmembers = tblmembers;
}
public String getMemberComments() {
    return this.memberComments;
}

public void setMemberComments(String memberComments) {
    this.memberComments = memberComments;
}
```

}

I am running the following Hibernate query and it is bring back the correct records

from Tbleventattendees a WHERE a.tblevent.eventId =1

however the foriegn key value shown is not the member ID it is the reference to the object e.g. Society.TblMembers.6a800ad6 any idea how I can bring back the foreign key value i.e. the value entered in the member ID field memberID in the database?

I then tried the following Inner Join

from Tbleventattendees a inner join a.eventId but it is telling me it is an invalid query
thanks

Richard

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: Kindly post your entity classes

Comment: Your mapping doesn't make sense. `tbleventattendeeses` must be a OneToMany; `tblevent` can't possibly be a OneToMany: a ToMany association must be a collection. Same for `tblmembers`. Use the singular form for your entities. Drop the Tbl prefix and respect the Java naming conventions. Read the Hibernate manual to learn how associations work.

Comment: I have now revised the code following comments, once I get this working I will correct the naming to match Java conventions. My 3 entity classes are now.